# Has anyone tested Akka-http-testkit?

Tags: scala, akka, karma-jasmine, microservices, akka-testkit

I'm working in a microservice architecture based in akka-http and akka clustering . I have seen in akka documentation this library [akka-http-testkit](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-M2/scala/http/index-testkit.html). Actually, it's in an experimental state , but haven't found any documentation . Seems it's on progress .

Has anyone used this library ? Can anyone suggest me any way to test rest microservices ? . My first option is using [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/index.html), and do the testing via javascript, but it would be great to hear different opinion and options (as Akka-http-testkit ... maybe ... :))

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a work in progress to me. I haven't use it myself, but you could check the [API documentation](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-RC4/?_ga=1.108323586.1208307473.1416240750#akka.http.scaladsl.testkit.package) along with [some tests](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/releasing-akka-stream-and-http-experimental-1.0-RC4/akka-http-testkit/src/test/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/testkit/ScalatestRouteTestSpec.scala).

My advice is: continue using Spray until akka-http is stable. Then you can use the [migration guide](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-RC4/scala/http/migration-from-spray.html) (which is also a work in progress ;))

Comment: It's more a proof-of-concept project . No production yet . Anyway, thanks for the response . For the moment, the API has been my only source of documentation . I have a lot of curiosity jajaja . Just that .